# Spring @Configuration bean created in @Bean method not enhanced by CGLIB

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I'm trying to create a MainConfig that imports another Config by using an @Bean method instead of @Import like this :

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfig {

  @Bean
  public Service service() {
    return new Service(infrastructureConfig().database());
  }

  @Bean
  public OtherService otherService() {
    return new OtherService(infrastructureConfig().database());
  }      

  @Bean
  public InfrastructureConfig intrastructureConfig() {
    return new InfrastructureConfig();
  }

}


@Configuration
public class InfrastructureConfig {

  @Bean
  public Database database() {
    return new Database();
  }

  ...
}
```

When using this technique, the Database is created twice because Spring doesn't seem to consider the @Configuration annotation on InfrastructureConfig. When using @Import, it works fine.

I don't want to use @Import because I want to mock my InfrastructureConfig like this :

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig extends MainConfig {

  @Override
  public InfrastructureConfig infrastructureConfig() {
    return mock(InfrastructureConfig.class);
  }
}
```

Am I missing something or it is not supported ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a Spring ticket [SpringSource JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9485) and they said that it is a known limitation and it is working as designed.

Answer (score 0):

When I first tried out Spring Java configuration I think I made the same assumption and was surprised when it didn't work.

I'm not sure this is the neatest way of solving this but I have used the following approach successfully.

To include that @Configuration class you can add this annotation to your `MainConfig`:

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.foo", includeFilters = {@Filter(filterType = ANNOTATION, value = CONFIGURATION)}, excludeFilters = {@Filter(filterType = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MainConfig)})`

Since @Configuration classes are also candidates for component scanning this allows you to scan for all classes annotated with @Configuration. Since you're putting this annotation on `MainConfig` you need to exclude that with the ASSIGNABLE_TYPE filter since you'll get a circular reference.